# Conditional Mutual information

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, entropy, information-theory

[image: The theoretical approach,i want to convert this into a python program[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpfqt.jpg)Was trying to test this package for calculation of conditional mutual information from a dataset .The package name-"dit"

My code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import dit
from dit import Distribution as D
from dit.multivariate import coinformation as I
from dit.example_dists import Xor

d=Xor()
d.set_rv_names(['X','Y','Z'])
X=111010
Y=101101
Z=001011

a=dit.multivariate.coinformation(d,'XY','Z')
print(a)
```

While running this program,the result i always get is "1.0".
The result come as negative or positive value like "-0.0023" or "0.120"

Basically,i want to do this 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147401/estimating-mutual-information-using-r
in Python.
A little bit of help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this is the solution for you: `set_rv_names` to `d`:

```
d=Xor()

## ADD THIS LINE OF CODE BELOW
d.set_rv_names(['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

X=0.052290766
Y=0.004951425
Z=0.000246642

a=dit.multivariate.coinformation(d,'XY','Z')
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for help. Are there like any other ways,i can do information theoretic approach problems with python.

Comment: Yes, you can also build models from scratch, as long as you have a consistent knowledge of information theory. You can use it in decision trees, gradient boosting, neural networks, to customize loss and tree split. Did the answer solve your problem ?

Comment: yes,it did! Thanks again. But do you know about any package that can help in this information theoretic approach?

Comment: Glad to know, please give an upvote for the answer, I'll be thankful. I suggest you to study theory to better understand the concepts, and also approach deep learning, Informational GANs, how tree based methods for classification work. For instance, you can customize the loss of a deep learning model using information theory, KL divergence, entropy, surprise, mutual information. I don't know a specific library for that.

Comment: I tried to put Binary values in X,Y,Z(X=101100, Y=010110,Z=110101). And i am getting invalid syntax error. Please help. @Rubens

Comment: Try this: `X=[1,1,0]`,`Y=[0,0,1]`,`Z=[0,1,1]`

Comment: while trying to install a python package named `mdentropy` i encountered this error 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NETRAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uly5kze9\mdtraj\' Can you help?

Comment: Pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres can `git` or another package compute the conditional mutual information matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It's already been a long time, but... If you just want to calculate conditional mutual information for DISCRETE r.v. use below code :

```
import pandas as pd

def conditional_mutual_information(data, X:set, Y:set, Z:set, delta = 1):
        X = list(X); Y = list(Y); Z = list(Z)
        cmi = 0

        P_Z = data.groupby(Z).size()
        P_Z = P_Z/P_Z.sum()

        P_XZ = data.groupby(X + Z).size()
        P_XZ = P_XZ/P_XZ.sum()

        P_YZ = data.groupby(Y + Z).size()
        P_YZ = P_YZ/P_YZ.sum()

        P_XYZ = data.groupby(X + Y + Z).size()
        P_XYZ = P_XYZ/P_XYZ.sum()

        for ind in P_XYZ.index:
            x_ind = ind[:len(X)]
            y_ind = ind[len(X):len(X + Y)]
            z_ind = ind[len(X + Y):]

            xz_ind = x_ind + z_ind
            yz_ind = y_ind + z_ind
            xyz_ind = ind

            z_ind =  pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([z_ind], names = Z) if len(Z) != 1 else pd.Index(z_ind, name = Z[0])
            xz_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([xz_ind], names = X + Z)
            yz_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([yz_ind], names = Y + Z)
            xyz_ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([xyz_ind], names = X + Y + Z)

            cmi += delta * P_XYZ[xyz_ind].item() * np.log2(P_Z[z_ind].item() * P_XYZ[xyz_ind].item() / (P_XZ[xz_ind].item() * P_YZ[yz_ind].item()))

        return cmi
```

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['X'] = [1,1,1,0,1,0]
data['Y'] = [1,0,1,1,0,1]
data['Z'] = [0,0,1,0,1,1]
conditional_mutual_information(data, {'X'}, {'Y'}, {'Z'})
>> [out] 0.25162916738782287
```

If you want to know how it works, "Conditional Mutual Information" part of [here](https://github.com/papamoon0113/Causal-Discovery-Python-Implement)